# How to show activity after Interstitial is loaded?

Tags: android, admob

There is an intermediate activity in my app where placed a few buttons, and I have a problem that after opening this activity most of the users click on button before ad is loaded. But when I'm trying to show ad after loading activity appears annoying delay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have also faced this very same issue. My Solution:

- Suppose there are 3 activities and opening sequence is as follows:

  ```
  Activity_A --> Activity_B --> Activity_C.
  ```
- Now I want to show interstitial Ad between `Activity_B` and `Activity_C`.
- I have first loaded the Interstitial Ad in Activity_A and then call(or show) in `Activity_C`.

You can do above like this:

In Activity_A i.e. MainActivity  add code like this:

```
public void showme(){

        mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);
        mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId(getString(R.string.interstitial_full_screen));
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
                .build();
        mInterstitialAd.loadAd(adRequest);

        mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener()
        {

            @Override
            public void onAdClosed()
            {
                //reload interstitial
                AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
//                        .addTestDevice("YOUR_DEVICE_ID")
                        .build();
                mInterstitialAd.loadAd(adRequest);
            }
        });
    }

    public static void showInterstitial() {
        if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
            mInterstitialAd.show();
        }
    }
```

Call this showme() in Activity_A inside OnCreate.

In Activity_C paste below code inside OnCreate:

```
Activity_A.showInterstitial();
```

Comment: My advice is to load Interstitial Ads in very first Activity (i.e. MainActivity) and then call it in any other activity.

Comment: There is another problem) I didn't find how to keep initialized and loaded InterstitialAd while switching activies.

Comment: Can you please create another question because it is different from this question asked. Also it help other people also..

Comment: Good thing about this method is that It doesn't violate any Admob policies.

Comment: It works good, but now fill rate is less than 2%. I know the reason of it, but think there is no solution.

Comment: What do you mean by fill rate? :)  I don't know about this term in this context.

Comment: Fill rate is the percentage of how many of requested ads were shown.